# How to mock AWS Cognito CognitoIdentityServiceProvider with Jest?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, jestjs, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to write unit test where I need to mock response of method from cognito service -
[CognitoIdentityServiceProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.htm)

I have the following working code calling the `adminInitiateAuth` operation

```js
import * from AWS from 'aws-sdk'


const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
const response = await cognito.adminInitiateAuth(expectedParams).promise();

// main functionality I want to test
```

and I want to have a spec where I try to mock this service as prerequisites

```js
const mockResponse = {
  AuthenticationResult: {
    AccessToken: 'expected-token'
  }
}

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
    return {
      CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: {
        adminInitiateAuth: () => {
          return mockResponse;
        }
      }
    }
});
```

this returns me an error

`AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider is not a constructor`

How this can not be a constructor?
Do you have any ideas how to mock it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. It may be useful to someone

```js
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
    return {
      CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: class {
        adminInitiateAuth() {
          return this;
        }

        promise() {
          return Promise.resolve(mockResponse);
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it if we want to use `spyOn` to mock a specific function:

```
const cognotoIdentityServiceProvider = Object.getPrototypeOf(new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider());
const stub = jest.spyOn(cognotoIdentityServiceProvider, 'adminDeleteUser').mockReturnValue({
  promise: () => Promise.resolve('bob johnson'),
});
```

Comment: This `Object.getPrototypeOf` method really helped in my case, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html)

```
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider', () => {
  return {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient: class {
      send() {
        return mockCognitoResponseAddGroup
      }

      promise() {
        return Promise.resolve({})
      }
    },
    CreateGroupCommand: class {},
  }
})
```

Comment: What would mockCognitoResponseAddGroup be?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  const cognito = { listUsers: jest.fn() };
  return {
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => cognito),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn(),
    },
  };
});

const mCognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
mCognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  return {
    promise() {
      return Promise.resolve('your mock data');
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.