# Mock JavaScript class in another file

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, aws-sdk-js

I have a function which uses the AWS sdk [source](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/cognito/actions/sign-up.js):

```
import {
  SignUpCommand,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import { createClientForDefaultRegion } from "../../libs/utils/util-aws-sdk.js";

const signUp = async ({ clientId, username, password, email }) => {
  const client = createClientForDefaultRegion(CognitoIdentityProviderClient);

  const command = new SignUpCommand({
    ClientId: clientId,
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
    UserAttributes: [{ Name: "email", Value: email }],
  });

  return client.send(command);
};
```

Now I want to write unit tests for this function. I've started with something like this:

```
describe('cognito', () => {
  it('should sign up a user', async () => {
    const clientId = '42'
    const username = 'tony.stark@example.com'
    const password = '1@m1r0nm@n'
    const expected = { UserConfirmed: true, UserSub: '1234567890'}
    const cognito = jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider')
    const result = await signUp(clientId, username, password)
    expect(result).toMatchObject(expected)
  })
})
```

How do I mock the classes from the AWS SDK so that the `new` commands in this function return a mock object created in my test?

p.s. Since posting this question, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73886822/144056), but my attempts to implement it aren't quite there yet. I have the following mock:

```
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider', () => {
  return {
    CognitoIdentityProvider: class {
      send() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve(expected)
        })
      }
    },
    SignUpCommand: class {}
  }
})
```

but my test still appears to calling the actual implementation in the aws sdk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the mock isn't entirely clear from the way I present the code in my question. I left out the `import` for the function I am testing. This was at the top of the file, as is typical convention. However, for the mock to work correctly, I had to create the mock first, then do the import. So my final solution looks like this:

```
const expected = { UserConfirmed: true, UserSub: '1234567890'}
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider', () => {
  return {
    CognitoIdentityProvider: class {
      send() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve(expected)
        })
      }
    },
    SignUpCommand: class {}
  }
});
import {signUp} from '../../app/users/users.cognito';

describe('cognito', () => {
  it('should sign up a user', async () => {
    const clientId = '42'
    const username = 'tony.stark@example.com'
    const password = '1@m1r0nm@n'
    const result = await signUp(clientId, username, password)
    expect(result).toMatchObject(expected)
  })
})
```

Thanks to [@mowwalker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72663255/1440565) for suggesting this solution.